# Two-path test proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

If we want to show that the limit of function of two variables doesn't exist , it is sufficient two paths which have different limits . Intuitively , it seems correct but how we can prove it with the using of definition of limit ?

Comment: Have you tried to prove it?  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes I tried , I don't know how a path is related to definition of limit .

Comment: The distance between two distinct points (the limits, in this case) is positive, say $d$. Consider the definition of a limit with $\varepsilon=d/4$.

Comment: A path is a continuous function.

Comment: @Clayton Can you explain more please ?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes but how we can use this fact to prove limit doesn't exist ?

Comment: Look at Clayton's comment more closely.

Comment: @saulspatz Unfortunately , I didn't get result with that hint .

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $D$ the domain of your function, and pick $x_0 \in D$.

If you want the classic $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity of $f$ at $x_0$, here it is:
$$\forall \varepsilon >0, \ \ \ \exists \delta >0 : \ \ \ \forall x \in D, \ \ \ |x-x_0|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$
Let's write the condition: "for some path the limit is $L$"
$$\gamma_1:[0,1] \to D \ \ \mathrm{continuous}, \ \ \ \gamma_1(1)=x_0, \ \ \ \lim_{t \to 1}f( \gamma_1 (t))=L$$

A similar condition for some second path, with limit $L' \neq L$:

$$\gamma_2:[0,1] \to D \ \ \mathrm{continuous}, \ \ \ \gamma_2(1)=x_0, \ \ \ \lim_{t \to 1}f( \gamma_2 (t))=L'$$

Now, pick $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{9}|L-L'|$, and $\delta$ accordingly to $(*)$. By continuity of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ at $t=1$, there esists $\delta_2$ such that
$$\forall t \in [0,1], \ \ |1-t|< \delta_2 \Rightarrow (|\gamma_1(t)- x_0| < \delta \ \ \ \ \wedge \ \ \ |\gamma_2(t)-x_0| < \delta)$$
Thus, by $(*)$ you have
$$|f(\gamma_1(t)) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \ \ \ \wedge \ \ \ |f(\gamma_2(t)) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$$

Moreover, there exists $\delta_3 >0$ such that
$$\forall t \in [0,1], \ \ |1-t|< \delta_3 \Rightarrow (|f(\gamma_1(t))- L| < \varepsilon \ \ \ \ \wedge \ \ \ |f(\gamma_2(t))-L'| < \varepsilon)$$
Finally, take any $t \in [0,1]$ with $t < \delta_2, \delta_3$. Then
$$|f( \gamma_1(t)) - f( \gamma_2(t))| = |(f( \gamma_1(t)) -f(x_0)) - ( f( \gamma_2(t))- f(x_0))| \le 2 \varepsilon= \frac{2}{9}|L-L'|$$
on the other hand
$$|f( \gamma_1(t)) - f( \gamma_2(t))|= |(f( \gamma_1(t))-L) - (f( \gamma_2(t))-L') + (L-L')|\ge |L-L'|- 2 \varepsilon = \\ = \frac{7}{9}|L-L'|$$
which is a contradiction.

Now, you can see that writing all of this using $\varepsilon - \delta$ becomes very heavy and tedious: this is the reason why nobody wanted to answer you in these terms.

Comment: Why $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ have $[0 , 1]$ domain ?

Comment: They are paths. Do you know what a path is?

Comment: Not exactly , I only encountered some examples like $y = mx$ or $x = y^2$ .

Comment: Well, for example, $y=mx$ is a formula for the path $\gamma(x)=(x,mx)$, where $x \to 0$. Now, if you call $t=1-x$, you have a continuous function of $t \to 1$ with $\gamma (1)=x_0$.

Comment: Sorry , I'm really confused . Can you give a precise definition of path please ?

Comment: A path on a set $D$ is a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1] \to D$. The points $\gamma(0) \in D$ and $\gamma(1) \in D$ are the beginning and the end of the path. The path is just a line connecting those two points.

Comment: So what about $(t^2 -1 , t^3 + 1)$ ? Is it a path ?

Comment: Yes, it is a path which parametrizes the curve $(x+1)^3=(y-1)^2$

Comment: Unfortunately , I'm still confused ! Is path in fact a function ? Or it doesn't have to be function in general ?